LOR deadline confusion
Hi quick question about deadlines. I am applying to the MA in health sys management and data analytics program. on the website the due date is Jan 15th for the application. the website says that we should have "completed application and supporting documentation is uploaded into the portal two weeks before the application deadline." - does this include like everything but the referee form and references? (like i should have my transcript, letter of intent, cv, etc. uploaded but the referee list with emails and names and their letters can wait until the actual deadline right?)
i tried asking the deparment but i'm still confused. the email bounced back since everyone's off starting today, but it says "Admissions tips for those applying to Grad Studies:
Supporting documents (including reference letters) can be submitted up to 14 days after the application deadline (i.e., December 29th for a December 15th deadline). "
Does this mean that by Jan 1 (2 weeks before the app deadline), i should have my cv, transcript, letter of intent, and writing sample uploaded? do i still have time to hold off on the supplementary information forms' page until Jan 15 (the page below)?
[the main page of the application website][1]
if anyone knows or has advice for me, i'd really appreciate it. so far i only have 1 reference and i'm waiting on the second. i just don't want to overwhelm them
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Ap4rHO8J.png

What exactly does the text before "completed application and supporting documentation is uploaded into the portal two weeks before the application deadline." say? It seems pointless to have a deadline when everything has to be done before.

@MisterMiyagi it does seem weird that they want everything done 2 weeks before. on the website it says this: Start early!!! It is the applicant's responsibility to ensure a completed application and supporting documentation is uploaded into the portal two weeks before the application deadline. Late applications or incomplete applications cannot be reviewed by the admissions committee.

This makes no sense. Saying that the application is due two weeks before the deadline is a contradiction in terms. And then saying you can submit certain documents after the deadline makes things worse. So unfortunately, this is not some convoluted-but-standard language that we can help you parse; this is just unclear, and you'll have to ask them for clarification.

Ok thanks for the reply, I'll try and get in touch with them in the new year @cag51
